# How Smash Nested Children SCSS Element

Tags: html, css, sass, nested

```
.parent{
  .child{
    height:100px;
  }  
}


.parent{
  .child{
    height:200px;
  }  
} /*THIS IS WORKING BUT I DONT WANT*/

.child{
    height:200px; /*THIS IS NOT WORKING*/
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px){
    .child{
        height:200px; /*ALSO THIS IS NOT WORKING*/
    }

    .parent{
      .child{
        height:200px;
      }  
    } /*THIS IS WORKING BUT I DONT WANT*/
}
```

How to smash old .child

I try to put end of the page the child, working with same nested structure but i want to use with just one classname, you can say not using nest child parent structure, but i use sass for to read easier.

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPEVJ.png)

Comment: Your English is hard to follow. You should use images or something to help us understand.

Comment: İ want to change style children without using nest.

Comment: try removing all scss besides ```.child```. You should be able to o what you want without a nest.

Comment: Yes i can but how i be able to with nest? if i not using nest, why i use scss.

Comment: `.parent{
  .child{
    height:200px;
  }  
}` is the same as `.parent .child { height: 200px; }`.

Comment: After .parent .child { height: 200px; },  .child {height:100px}  child not being 100px?

Comment: because `.parent .child {}` has a higher specificity than `.child {}`. You should read the basics of css.

Comment: i know, that is the my question, i ask how i smash ".parent .child{}" with using just .child. When project getting bigger in sass getting harder to find which parent has which child.